# Как сделать видимыми на Stroryboard элементы которые устанавливаются динамически?

Tags: xcode, swift

Все, что я устанавливаю динамически можно увидеть только запустив приложение, но это не совсем удобно, так как я устанавливаю бекграунд своему `View Controller` и `title` для `lable` тоже ставлю из кода. Когда открываю `Storyboard` то ничего не видно...

Я знаю что есть такая аннотация `@IBDesignable` которая вроде решает как раз эту проблему, но в моем случае это почему то не работает((

Как сделать?

**Правка**

Создал класс

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавил View на скрине видна иерархия и инспекция этого вью

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот так применяю

```
import UIKit

class SplashViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    GradientView().backgroundColor = CustomColors().takeColor(color: .greyColor)

}
```

Не хочет показывать фон бекграунда(

Вот результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае Ваша ошибка, что нужно это делать для элемента, который должен быть изменен. Т.е. чтоб были видны изменения фона `UIView`, для `UIView` и нужно написать соответствующий класс. Пример по Вашему прошлому вопросу:

```
@IBDesignable class GradientView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var gradientBackground: UIColor {
        set {
            let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
            gradientLayer.frame = bounds
            gradientLayer.colors = [newValue.cgColor, UIColor.lightGray.cgColor, newValue.cgColor]
            gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
            gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
            gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image!)
        }
        get {
            return backgroundColor!
        }
    }
}
```

И как это выглядит в интерфейс билдере:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так понял, что если создаем класс для вью , то на сам сториборд нужно добавить эту кастомную вью, верно? Я добавил ее в инспекторе указал ей класс `GradientView` и во `ViewController` в методе `viewDidLoad()` выполнил вот такую строчку `GradientView().backgroundColor = CustomColors().takeColor(color: .greyColor)` , но все равно не отображается фон ни на симуляторе , ни в сториборд... Не понятно, что сделал не так?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko да, добавили `UIView`, прописали ей `ИмяСвоегоIBDesignableКласса`. `ViewController` уже не связан с `View` здесь. Чтоб  были видны изменения добавляйте цвет в сеттере переменной (ну для случая  в примере) `gradientBackground`. По примеру - в интерфейс билдере можно менять цвет `Gradient Background` и будет градиент `выбранный цвет - серый - выбранный цвет`

Comment: Добавил правку в вопрос, описал все со скриншотами, где сделал не так?)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko попробуйте в `Gradient Background` в интерфейс билдере изменить цвет. Может дефолтный не вызывает  `set.`

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю то set будет вызван тогда когда я попробую присвоить переменной gradientBackground какое то значение, верно? Я присваиваю ей это значение из SplashViewController   вот в этой строке `GradientView().backgroundColor = CustomColors().takeColor(color: .greyColor)`

Comment: Когда вы сказали "Может дефолтный не вызывает set." - это вы про что говорили? Ведь я не устанавливаю дефолтный, я конкретно указываю какой цвет я присваиваю `GradientView().backgroundColor = CustomColors().takeColor(color: .greyColor)`

Comment: Все разобрался))

Comment: Спасибо) Теперь понял, это первый раз я работаю с кастомным вью ) Получается когда указываем переменной `@IBInspectable` то получаем к ней доступ из `Storyboard` и вот там нам и нужно было поменять это дефолтное значение) Спасибо!